# What's the difference between these two given examples

Tags: c++, structure, declaration, variable-declaration, string.h

I'm a beginner in C++ and programming itself actually. I just want to ask, What's the difference between these 2 examples. What is the difference between "len = strlen(str1)-1" and "i = strlen(str1)-1"

Top part of the code will be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str1[20],str2[20];
    int c, i ,j, len;
    
    cout<<"Enter a word: ";
    cin.getline(str1, 20);
```

Example 1:

```
//reverse
for (i = strlen(str1)-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++){
    str2[j] = str1[i];      
}
//compare string
c = strcmp(str1, str2);

/*This does not work because the value of 'c' will be -1 if the input
is "lol" which is palindrome*/
```

and Example 2:

```
//reverse
len = strlen(str1)-1;
for (i = len, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++){
    str2[j] = str1[i];      
}

//compare string
c = strcmp(str1, str2);

/*This does work in other hand, because of the variable "len"*/
```

the rest of the code will be like this

```
if(c == 0){
    cout<<"It is a Palindrome";
}
//if the value of C is !=0
else{
    cout<<"It is not a Palindrome";
}

}
```

Why is that? Thanks in advance for those who will answer. :)

Comment: "this returns 0 if the strs are palindromes" - what?  does it?

Comment: The -1 is because C++ container indexing starts at `0`, not `1`. So the final element in an `n`-element container has index `n-1` not index `n`.

Comment: This is not answerable as it stands. Your comments mention a return that is not present in the code. You also haven't included the types of the used variables, nor how both strings are initialized. Please amend your question.

Comment: Hi, Sander De Dycker, I have edited my question hope this clarifies it. :)

Comment: @Programming_Student I have updated the answer. Although the code has lot of scope to improve but this should be good enough to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples are same except first uses an extra variable `len`.

This code is actually reversing the string. If `str1` contains *"123"* then `str2` will contain *"321"*.

Function `strlen(str1)` returns the length of `str1` but in C++ index of Arrays start from `0` that is why the last element index will be one less than length, hence `strlen(str1) - 1`.

**UPDATE**

Even with updated information the answer to first question remains same that both examples are same in nature. Difference in results is a mare co-incident due to a reason explained below.

`char str1[20],str2[20];`

This code creates two array of 20 `char` but not initialized. This means the initial values can be random.

Now when you call `cin.getline(str1, 20);` it not only writes the string you entered but adds a terminating `'\0'` character at the end of it. Our reversing logic only reverse the string but does not insert terminating `'\0'` at the end of `str2` which means `str2` is much longer (until it finds a `'\0'`) than `str1`. Due to this they never compare correctly.

A simple solution to this issue can be zero-filling the arrays before using them and in C++ there is a simple way to do that:

`char str1[20] = { 0 }, str2[20] = { 0 };`

It is always a good practice to zero-fill your arrays if you are going to use then as strings.